# System.getenv still picks up deleted env variable value on MacOS Mojave - Java

Tags: java, environment-variables, system, macos-mojave

I added some exportable environment variables in my bash_profile and my profile files in the following format export "X=y". This worked as it should, now I want to remove them permanently . I've tried the following methods:

1. Deleting the exported variables from the bash_profile and the profile files, and saving the files, and calling source ~/.bash_profile and source ~/.profile.
2. Called "unset X" in terminal window. Before I could call "echo $X" which would display y, now it displays nothing.
3. Rebooting the Mac Computer.

Still however, whenever I call Java's System.getenv(X), env variable X's value (y) is still returned. What else do I need to do to completely eliminate an env variable from my system in MacOS Mojave?

Comment: On my Windows box, a reboot of the PC usually is required for the updated environment list (whether added or deleted) to be read in.

Comment: Forgot to add I rebooted my mac and still get the same result.

Comment: have you checked any other files like `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I checked ~/.bashrc , is there any other files that I need to be aware of? Thanks Ivan.

Comment: You need to explain how you are launching the java program. Also, now that you have removed the var from your personal bash profile what happens if you `echo $X` in a new terminal instance?

Comment: I am launching my Java application through Tomcat 8.5 which targets a packaged WAR file of my application. Calling echo $X prints nothing to the terminal, just a blank line. Above I stated that before I called unset X, I could call echo $X which would print y, however after I call unset X, echo $X prints nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you believe environment variables are global. That is, modifying the value in one program, such as a running terminal, will affect the value in a different program. That is not how env vars work in a UNIX like OS. Each process is provided a copy of the env vars provided by the parent process. That is, they are inherited from the parent process.

The fact that you have to `unset X` in a terminal to remove it means that either it is being inherited by the shell from the terminal process or your shell is setting it. In the latter case the specific files read when a shell starts depends on the shell. But */etc/profile* is read by most interactive shells so you might want to look there.

You say your Java app is run by Tomcat but failed to mention how Tomcat is started. That is important for the reasons I mention above.

Note that macOS uses a daemon named `launchd` to manage running most services. Those services are configured via "plist" files. See `man launchd.plist`. Those launchd config files support defining custom env vars. That is slightly unusual but worth looking at. See if any of the files in *~/Library/LaunchAgents*, */Library/LaunchAgents*, or */Library/LaunchDaemons* mention the env var.

Comment: I don't see anything in the LaunchAgents or Daemons, However I do start tomcat via terminal using the catalina.sh file.

Comment: What is the first line of `catalina.sh`? If it is something like `#!/bin/bash` then it won't read any dot files unless env var `BASH_ENV` is set. When you run that script did you first verify that `X` (or whatever it is named) is not set?